# Checking for Hardware Problems

Tags: hardware

I installed Ubuntu on a decent laptop. It runs another OS fine. However, Ubuntu sometimes crashes or gets frozen. I suspect that there's a a hardware problem, because numeric keyboard of this laptop does not work. Is there a way of checking my computer for a hardware problem? Sorry about my ignorance.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If it runs another OS fine, then the hardware is not *faulty*, but it might be merely *incompatible* with Ubuntu. We would need to know more about your hardware, and about the release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have an Intel "Bay Trail" processor?